# How to write a select field using the function React.createElement() in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i have this code  written in html

```
<select id ='Font_Size' onchange="ChangeFont()">
            <option>Font Size </option>
            <option id ='sizeUp'>Large </option>
            <option id ='normal'>Normal</option>
            <option id ='sizeDown'>Small</option>
</select>

React.createElement('input',{type:'select',onChange:this.ChangeFont},React.createElement("input",{type:"Option"}))
```

but i would like to create a react element that will create a selection field using  the function React.createElement() and display it as the above code would. the code at the bottom is what i had tried but it does not work

Comment: I believe the element type should be `select`, not `input`. I think what you wrote would generate html something like `<input type="select" onchange=...`

Comment: i don't think i understand...what is want to do is rewrite the select tag and its options using the React.createElement() function

Comment: @mihiali I've added an answer demonstrating how to do it

Comment: Thank you Ted..ill try it out

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you were creating was an `<input/>`, you want to create a `<select/>`. Run the following snippet to see the code in action:

```js
var App = React.createClass({
  render() {
    return React.createElement("select", {},
      React.createElement("option", {value: "A"}, "Option A"),
      React.createElement("option", {value: "B"}, "Option B"),
      React.createElement("option", {value: "C"}, "Option C")
    );
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(<App label="this is the label prop" />, document.getElementById('react'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.6.2/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/15.6.2/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Comment: It Worked thanks Ted.. i didn't understand how to add the options